# tooltip in highlight-regexp

Tags: tooltip

I'd like to get a tooltip that says "meow", whenever my mouse is on the word "Cat" in Emacs. I tried this snippet I put together, but didn't work. What's wrong with it?

```
(defun my-hi-lock ()
(interactive)
(highlight-regexp "Cat"  '(help-echo "meow!"))
)
```

I'd like to put the **associated** tooltip message inside the highlight-regexp statement rather than define a font face at a different place because I won't reuse each tooltip message that I'm going to assign to different keywords.

Comment: You don't need `highlight-regexp` for this (and you don't need font-lock either). Just put text-property `help-echo` on the buffer text for which you want the mouseover tooltip.

Comment: @Drew, is that permanent? How do you do that? Does it write something in your init file?

Comment: The property is not persisted in the file, no. You just define a function that you invoke in whatever buffer (e.g. on a mode hook, for buffers of a given mode), and which searches for a pattern and applies the property. Or have the searching be done automatically by font-lock-mode, as @Lindydancer suggests. My point was only that it is text-property `help-echo` (not font-lock, for example) that is responsible for the tooltip. See functions `put-text-property`, `add-text-properties`, and `set-text-properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highlight-regexp` seems to assume that the value is a symbol which is defined as a face, it doesn't work with lists. However, the function is just a wrapper around `font-lock-add-keywords`, fortunately, you can call this function directly, for example:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil
 '(("Cat" (0 '(face font-lock-warning-face help-echo "meow!")))))
```

This will set the `face` property to `font-lock-warning-face` (feel free to pick a better one, or use `nil`) and the `help-echo` property to `"meow!"`. Note that the symbol `face` must be the first entry in the list.

Note: If you do this, you must also put `help-echo` into `font-lock-extra-managed-props`, see the documentation of the variable `font-lock-keywords` for details.

For a concrete example, see `emacs-lisp-mode`.